# I am trying to recreate the flutter docs app but something won't work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

this is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: ListViewTests(),
    );
  }
}

class _ListViewTestsState extends State<ListViewTests> {
  Widget listViewTest() {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemBuilder: (context, item) {
          item += 1;
          if (item.isOdd) return const Divider();
          return listTileTest(item);
        });
  }

  Widget listTileTest(int item) {
    return const ListTile(
      title: Text('hello'),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: ListViewTests(),
    );
  }
}

class ListViewTests extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListViewTests({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListViewTestsState createState() => _ListViewTestsState();
}
```

What I want it to do is make a list of numbers that generate as the user scrolls. This code does basically nothing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text("Here is Item $index"),
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
          itemCount: 10),
    );
  }
}
```